# "Aw, Snap!" and ASR: No room in socket buffer errors in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, google-chrome, dom

I have a web application with heavy JS scripts (by heavy I mean lots of client processing which can't be done on the server side).
After 1 hour or so (not constant) of processing I get Chrome's *"Aw, Snap!"* error, I have debugged as suggest in https://superuser.com/questions/607563/how-to-determine-what-is-causing-chrome-to-show-the-aw-snap-dialogue and I noticed that everytime I get the error, the log is prompting `WARNING:audio_sync_reader.cc(177)] ASR: No room in socket buffer.`

I strongly believe that I am kind of running out of memory, because if I open other tabs after this error I get others *"Aw, Snap!"*.

However, considering that my JS script is long and it takes a long time to throw the error, how can I identify which piece of code is raising it?

PS.: I also have many DOM manipulations (mainly insertions on a table)

Thanks!

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but have you used the Developer Tools pane to watch resource consumption? Beyond that, the general debugging technique of divide and conquer (read [MCVE]) applies. Yes, it could be a long and tedious process. Welcome to the jungle ;)

Comment: Same happened to me using tone.js, if you do, check here https://github.com/Tonejs/Tone.js/issues/353

Answer (score 0):

Its not necessarily a certain line or a block of code. Its just that your application consumes to much memory. That can be caused by a a memory leak, which you can identify by looking at the debuggers memory tab. If no memory is leaking you should overthink your codes structure.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue:

```
[0225/064309.871791:WARNING:audio_sync_reader.cc(175)] ASR: No room in socket buffer.: Broken pipe (32)
```

I was running Chrome in headless mode in a Docker container. The warning above was caused by another memory issue related to the `/dev/shm` shared memory space of Linux. This page describes it in more detail:

https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md#tips

Docker only allocates 64MB for `/dev/shm`. I suppose that Chrome use `/dev/shm` to store images (uncompressed) which are loaded by the current browser tab. At least this would explain why Chrome only failed, when the website contained one or more large images. The `ASR: No room in socket buffer.` error was only a side-effect of occupying `/dev/shm` with the large images.

Using the `--disable-dev-shm-usage` Chrome command line flag solved this issue.